# BlackBerry:Fixed height VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, scrollbar

I have a VerticalFieldManager which acts as a parent.I have added 
one VFM & one HFM to the parent VFM.I want the VFM added to the parent VFM 
to behave as a fixed size VFM and the conents in it should be scolled 
only on scrolling.The HFM added to the parent VFM should be constantly seen 
on the screen.

In short i have to display a Toolbar at the bottom of the BB screen.
I have already created a custom class by extending HFM to display a toolbar.
And only when i scroll the VFM placed in the center i should be able to
see the remaining contents.

can any one give me some idea or code to implement this?

Regards,
Yogesh Chaudhari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [MainScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html) and the method setStatus.  They should do what you want.

Comment: Thank You so much Michael for giving me this one line excellent solution.Since i am new to BB i was thinking of so much code to get this done and u gave me the solution in just one line.Thank you so much dear